# Remove item from list by clicking ImageView

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove an item from the created list via clicking the image view. I want only to set the specific image view to carry out this task. (at the moment is not responding at all)

At the same time if the user would click different image view within the same item of the list they would open new activity. 
Here is code:

```
private void registerClickCallBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMyDiaryFood);
    /*nextImage.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });*/
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyDiaryConsumedFoodListItem clickedRecName = myConsumedFood
                    .get(position);
            String message = "" + clickedRecName.getRecipe_name_diary();
            // String message = "You clicked position " + position
            // + " of which recipe name is " + clickedFav.getRecipe_name();
            Toast.makeText(MyDiaryConsumedFood.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Can use also: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String rec_name = myConsumedFood.get(position)
                    .getRecipe_name_diary();
            String rec_id = myConsumedFood.get(position).getRecipeId();

                Intent i = new
            Intent(MyDiaryConsumedFood.this,RecipesDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("rec_name", recipe_name);
            System.out.println(rattype);
            i.putExtra("rec_id", recipe_id);

            startActivity(i);


            deleteView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDeleteMyDiary);
            deleteView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    //List<String> addedRecipe = _AddedRecipeToADay.get(_DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition));


                                    //addedRecipe.remove(childPosition);

                                    //plannerCalendar.deleteRecipeFromADay(recipeID, _DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition));
                                    //_DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition) = date("Mon 04/11/2013")
                                    //_AddedRecipeToADay.get(_DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) = Recipe Name in the selected position


                                    //notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    try {
                    alertDialog.show();
                    } catch(Exception e){
                           // WindowManager$BadTokenException will be caught and the app would not display 
                           // the 'Force Close' message
                         }
                }

            });

        }

    });

}
```

Not sure why the delete is not responding.......

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in startActivity (i)
Is invoked when you call startActivity other activity interrupted the execution of all subsequent code;

My suggestion is;

```
private void registerClickCallBack() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMyDiaryFood);
/*nextImage.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});*/
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyDiaryConsumedFoodListItem clickedRecName = myConsumedFood
                .get(position);
        String message = "" + clickedRecName.getRecipe_name_diary();
        // String message = "You clicked position " + position
        // + " of which recipe name is " + clickedFav.getRecipe_name();
        Toast.makeText(MyDiaryConsumedFood.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Can use also: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String rec_name = myConsumedFood.get(position)
                .getRecipe_name_diary();
        String rec_id = myConsumedFood.get(position).getRecipeId();          


        deleteView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDeleteMyDiary);
        deleteView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //List<String> addedRecipe = _AddedRecipeToADay.get(_DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition));


                                //addedRecipe.remove(childPosition);

                                //plannerCalendar.deleteRecipeFromADay(recipeID, _DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition));
                                //_DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition) = date("Mon 04/11/2013")
                                //_AddedRecipeToADay.get(_DayOfTheWeekHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) = Recipe Name in the selected position


                                //notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                try {
                alertDialog.show();
                } catch(Exception e){
                       // WindowManager$BadTokenException will be caught and the app would not display 
                       // the 'Force Close' message
                     }
            }

        });

        Intent i = new
        Intent(MyDiaryConsumedFood.this,RecipesDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("rec_name", recipe_name);
        System.out.println(rattype);
        i.putExtra("rec_id", recipe_id);

        startActivity(i);
    }

});
```

}